# Twitter Bootstrap alert message close and open again

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I have a problem with alert messages. It is displayed normally, and I can close it when the user presses `x` (close), but when the user tries to display it again (for example, click on the button event) then it is not shown. (Moreover, if I print this alert message to console, it is equal to `[]`.) My code is here:

```
 <div class="alert" style="display: none">
   <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
   <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
 </div>
```

And event:

```
 $(".alert").show();
```

**P.S!** I need to show alert message only after some event happened (for example, button clicked). Or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Data-dismiss completely removes the element. Use jQuery's .hide() method instead.

**The fix-it-quick method:**

Using inline javascript to hide the element onclick like this:

```
<div class="alert" style="display: none"> 
    <a class="close" onclick="$('.alert').hide()">×</a>  
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.  
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="$('alert').show()">show</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cQNFL/

*This should however only be used if you are lazy (which is no good thing if you want an maintainable app).*

**The do-it-right method:**

Create a new data attribute for hiding an element.

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("[data-hide]").on("click", function(){
        $("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide()
        // -or-, see below
        // $(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide()
    })
})
```

and then change data-dismiss to data-hide in the markup. [Example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQNFL/21/).

```
$("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide()
```

This will hide all elements with the class specified in data-hide, i.e: `data-hide="alert"` will hide all elements with the alert class.

[Xeon06](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104999/xeon06) provided an alternative solution:

```
$(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide()
```

This will only hide the closest parent element. This is very useful if you don't want to give each alert a unique class. Please note that, however, you need to place the close button within the alert.

Definition of .closest from [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Comment: Note: The inline Javascript was just for demonstration. A much nicer solution would be to use [$(..).on("click", ..)](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event handlers instead to avoid cluttering the markup.

Comment: Hey! Regarding your do it right answer. This will hide EVERY element that has the same class (ie, `alert`) on the page. A solution for this would be to replace the contents of the callback with this line `$(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();`, which will only affect the closest parent element, seeing as the dismiss button is typically placed within the alert it affects.

Comment: That is true, I didn't think of making it work that way. That will, however, remove the simplicity of this solution to a small extent. I'll add it as an comment to  the existing code. Thanks!

Comment: New to this.. where would you define the '$(function(){..'

Comment: Anywhere in a JavaScript file or in a <script>code here</script> tag.

Comment: As of Bootstrap 3, you can do `.addClass('hidden')` to have the same effect as `.hide()`.

Comment: If you would use $(document).on('click', '[data-hide]', function() { /* */ }) Your answer would be perfect ;)

Comment: @shock_gone_wild I think that would depend on the use case. Adding the event listener will force jQuery to check every click on the page, which isn't optimal. It probably won't matter, but if you aren't creating the dialogs dynamically there's no reason for that

Answer (score 27):

I just used a model variable to show/hide the dialog and removed the `data-dismiss="alert"`

**Example:**

```
<div data-ng-show="vm.result == 'error'" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="vm.result = null" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <strong>Error  !  </strong>{{vm.exception}}
</div>
```

works for me and stops the need to go out to jquery

Answer (score 19):

I think a good approach to this problem would be to take advantage of Bootstrap's `close.bs.alert` event type to hide the alert instead of removing it. The reason why Bootstrap exposes this event type is so that you can overwrite the default behavior of removing the alert from the DOM.

```
$('.alert').on('close.bs.alert', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using an MVVM library such as knockout.js (which I highly recommend) you can do it more cleanly:

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" data-bind="visible:showAlert">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-bind="click:function(){showAlert(false);}>
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
   </button>
   Warning! Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bce9gsav/5/

Comment: `data-bind="click:function(){showAlert(false);}` is a perfect example of **obtrusive** javascript which is far from being _cleaner_. I strongly recommend **NOT** to follow this approach

Comment: @Leo obtrusive in what way?

Comment: Obtrusive in every single way. You are actively "embedding" behaviour to your html structure/markup. Imagine you had to change that behaviour...how many pages and html elements you will have to change? Don't get me wrong, it still answers the question asked and that's why I will not downvote it. But this is far from a "cleaner" solution

Comment: No, what I'm actually saying is **use separation of concerns**. Your views (html) should never contain any javascript, the negative implications could be huge in a dev team. Here is great question (and answers) about Knockout and the somewhat controversial `data-bind` attribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451414/unobtrusive-knockout

Comment: What do you consider "JavaScript"? What if it only contained the name of the method to invoke? Is it the fact that it calls it with a parameter (false) that makes it obtrusive in your eyes?

Comment: Yes. It will still be obtrusive to both users AND developers. What I consider Javascript is irrelevant, I'm referring to the separation of markup, layout and **behaviour**. If you aren't familiar with that practice (which I doubt), there are plenty of resources out there covering the pros and cons in detail

Comment: @Leo what I mean is, were it written like this would you be OK with it? `data-bind="click:hideAlert"`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me best:

```
$('.alert').on('close.bs.alert', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So if you want a solution that can cope with dynamic html pages, as you already include it you should use jQuery's live to set the handler on all elements that are now and in future in the dom or get removed.

I use

```js
$(document).on("click", "[data-hide-closest]", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest($this.attr("data-hide-closest")).hide();
});
```

```css
.alert-success {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    color: #3c763d;
}
.alert {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.close {
    color: #000;
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: 0.2;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <a class="close" data-hide-closest=".alert">×</a>
  <strong>Success!</strong> Your entries were saved.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the above solutions use external libraries, either angular or jQuery, and an old version of Bootstrap. So, here is Charles Wyke-Smith's solution in **pure JavaScript**, applied to **Bootstrap 4**. Yes, Bootstrap requires jQuery for its own modal and alerts code, but not everyone writes their own code with jQuery any more.

Here is the html of the alert:

```
<div id="myAlert" style="display: none;" 
    class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> You did it!
</div>
```

Note that initially the alert is hidden (`style="display: none;"`), and instead of the standard `data-dismiss="alert"`, we have here used `data-hide="alert"`.

Here is the JavaScript to show the alert and override the close button:

```
var myAlert = document.getElementById('myAlert');
// Show the alert box
myAlert.style.display = 'block';
// Override Bootstrap's standard close action
myAlert.querySelector('button[data-hide]').addEventListener('click', function() {
    myAlert.style.display = 'none';
});
```

If you wish to hide or show the alert programmatically elsewhere in the code, just do  `myAlert.style.display = 'none';` or `myAlert.style.display = 'block';`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well and the the problem with simply hacking the close-button is that I still need access to the standard bootstrap alert-close events.

My solution was to write a [small, customisable, jquery plugin](https://github.com/davesag/jquery-bs3Alert) that injects a properly formed Bootstrap 3 alert (with or without close button as you need it) with a minimum of fuss and allows you to easily regenerate it after the box is closed.

See https://github.com/davesag/jquery-bs3Alert for usage, tests, and examples.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer posted by Henrik Karlsson and edited by Martin Prikryl.  I have one suggestion, based on accessibility.  I would add .attr("aria-hidden", "true") to the end of it, so that it looks like:

```
$(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).attr("aria-hidden", "true");
```

Comment: Is that really needed? jQuerys .hide function sets display: none, shouldn't screen readers be smart enough to recognize it as hidden anyways?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by using the `style="display:none"`, you should hide the *alert* with Javascript or at least when showing it, remove the style attribute.

Comment: Not really, the problem is Data-dismiss removing the element

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers and changing data-dismiss to data-hide, this example handles opening the alert from a link and allows the alert to be opened and closed repeatedly

```
$('a.show_alert').click(function() {
    var $theAlert = $('.my_alert'); /* class on the alert */
    $theAlert.css('display','block');
   // set up the close event when the alert opens
   $theAlert.find('a[data-hide]').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().hide(); /* hide the alert */
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the methods and the best way for me is to use the built-in bootstrap classes  `.fade` and `.in`

Example:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade <?php echo ($show) ? 'in' : '' ?>" role="alert">...</div>
```

*Note: In jQuery, addClass('in') to show the alert, removeClass('in') to hide it.*

*Fun fact: This works for all elements. Not just alerts.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550556/1115187) by [Henrik Karlsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502126/henrik-karlsson) but with proper **event triggering** (based on [Bootstrap sources](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/2c2ac3356425e192f7537227508c809a14aa5850/js/alert.js#L25)):

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-hide]').on('click', function ___alert_hide(e) {
        var $this = $(this)
        var selector = $this.attr('data-target')
        if (!selector) {
            selector = $this.attr('href')
            selector = selector && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') // strip for ie7
        }

        var $parent = $(selector === '#' ? [] : selector)

        if (!$parent.length) {
            $parent = $this.closest('.alert')
        }

        $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('close.bs.alert'))

        if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

        $parent.hide()

        $parent.trigger($.Event('closed.bs.alert'))
    })
});
```

The answer mostly for me, as a note.

Answer (score 0):

Can this not be done simply by adding a additional "container" div and adding the removed alert div back into it each time. Seems to work for me?

HTML

```
<div id="alert_container"></div>
```

JS

```
 $("#alert_container").html('<div id="alert"></div>');          
 $("#alert").addClass("alert alert-info  alert-dismissible");
 $("#alert").html('<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Info!</strong>message');
```

Answer (score 0):

**There's a very simple way to do this using JQuery**

If you delete `data-dismiss="alert"` from the alert div, you can just hide the alert using the `x` button, by adding a click events and interacting with the `display` css attribute of the alert.

```
$(".close").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
});
```

Then, whenever you need it again, you can toggle the `display` attribute again.

**Full Example:**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="my_alert" style="display: none;">
   Uh Oh... Something went wrong
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<script>
   $(".close").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
   });

   //Use whatever event you like
   $("#show_alert").click(function(){
      $("#my_alert).css("display", "inherit");
   });
<script>
```