# Twitter Bootstrap alert message closes without pressing close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with alert messages. I want to use the alert message as a warning to the user after a particular action has been performed. The issue I am facing is that the message shows and then closes on its own without user closing the message.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="alert span10 offset1" style="display: none" id="changeStatusMsg"> 
    <a class="close" onclick="$('.alert').hide()" href="#">×</a>  
        <strong>Status has been changed.</strong>  
</div>
```

I am using jquery to show the message -- $('#changeStatusMsg').show();
I used the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550477/twitter-bootstrap-alert-message-close-and-open-again)
But it does not help in my case.

```
function changeStatus(status, widgetExternalId){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'Controller',
        data : { 'widget' : widgetExternalId, 
                 'method' : (status == 'I' ? "activate" : "inactivate")
               },
        success : function(data) {
                window.location = "myaccount.jsp";
                $('#changeStatusMsg').show();
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't use a user style, that's your issue. Use a style sheet style. User style overrides everything.

Just call it javascript to show it, then let the onclick handler make it go away. User style is the issue.

Comment: Hu? http://jsfiddle.net/cQNFL/1/

Comment: How are you showing it? I bet it has to do the fact you are not cancelling that action.

Comment: I am calling the show() method on success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably do to the fact you are not calling the action that is opening it. So the page is refreshing.

If you are doing it inline:

```
onclick="$('#changeStatusMsg').show();return false;"
```

If with a click event

```
$(".foobar").on("click",function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#changeStatusMsg').show();
});
```

Comment: I am calling the show() method after a action is being performed. I make an ajax call change the status. On success I want to display the message.

Comment: Oh. I got the problem. Making such a stupid mistake. I ported the code from another page, did not need to use window.location.