# Hide alert when click on close button instead remove it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my page, the response from server is displayed using this alert:

```
    <div id="yes" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <strong>Pronto!</strong> cadastro efetuado com sucesso! 
    </div>
```

Is there any way to when I click in the close button from the alert, it be hide instead removed from page? I try this (following instructions from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts)), without success:

```
$('#my-alert').on('close.bs.alert', function () {
  $(this).hide();
})
```

**UPDATE**

I also try this:

```
    $('button.close').on("click", function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
```

but still the same problem, when I click in the close button, the alert is removed.

Comment: `hide` doesn't remove  elements, what is the problem?

Comment: @undefined I don't want remove, but this is what happens when I click in the close button.

Comment: The element is removed by the bootstrap not by the `hide` call.

Comment: I solve this issue following the instructions from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13550556/2692962

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap alert message close and open again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550477/twitter-bootstrap-alert-message-close-and-open-again)

Comment: I solve this issue with this tip: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13550556/2692962

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution I found for this problem:

> Create a new data attribute for hiding an element.
>
> Javascript:
>
> ```
> $(function(){
>     $("[data-hide]").on("click", function(){
>         $("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
>         // -or-, see below
>         // $(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> and then change data-dismiss to data-hide in the markup. Example at
>   jsfiddle.
>
> ```
> $("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
> ```
>
> This will hide all elements with the class specified in data-hide,
>   i.e: data-hide="alert" will hide all elements with the alert class.

based on the answer posted in this topic: [Twitter Bootstrap alert message close and open again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550477/twitter-bootstrap-alert-message-close-and-open-again)

Answer (score 4):

Use the bootstrap close.bs.alert event:

```
$('.alert').on('close.bs.alert', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
  });
```

Comment: I use `$(this).fadeOut()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried these solutions, but not working for me.
You can do it with simply remove "data-dismiss" attribute from your markup and create new function :

```
    $('.alert').on('click','.close',function(){
        $(this).closest('.alert').slideUp();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it with help of above comments and removed "data-dismiss"

```
$('.close').on('click', function(e) {
     $('.alert').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[that above answer is correct but there are one issue So, place this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966367/14344959)

click event detect using **`[data-hide=alert]`** is better than **`[data-hide]`**. because If you could used data-hide attribute multiple times in same screen then for hide specific div then you faced issue. so, detect click event with **[{yourAttributeName}={attributeValue}]** value also

```
$("[data-hide=alert]").on("click", function(){ 
     $("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
     // -OR-
     // $(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
     
     // -OR-
     // ... do stuff as above answer 
     // otherwise do changes as per your need
}
```

Answer (score -2):

your are doing it wrong try this as in your case the button class is close and div id is yes

```
$('button.close').on('click', function () {
  $("#yes").hide();
})
```