# How to eliminate an object to satisfy my if statement

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using JQuery Autocomplete. It works fine. However, if a person enters a customer name where there is no result I want to display a Bootstrap error message. That also works BUT **only the first time**. If you make a second entry into the search field which is also wrong, then the `if ((data.length == 0) || $.isEmptyObject(data) || (data == null) )` renders `TRUE` but regardless I do not get my error message. I even try to empty the data object after the alert. I have also placed `console.log()` messages throughout the if statement to ensure that I am not making an error in terms of process flow. I can see that the `if()` statement is being triggered. But somehow the alert only works on the first pass. So what have I done wrong ? TKS!

```
$('#customer').autocomplete({
    minLength:3,
    source: function(request, response,term) {

        var param = request.term;
        $.ajax({
            url: "quotes/customer_search/"+param,
            dataType: "json",
            type:"GET",
            success: function (data) { console.log('l 132',data);
                if ((data.length == 0) || $.isEmptyObject(data) || (data == null) )  console.log('l 133', data)
                { $("#search_customer").addClass("alert alert-warning fade in").append('No Such Person Found',"<a href='#' class=close data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close' title='close'>×</a>" ); /* .hide(5000); */
               delete data ; console.log('l 135', data);

                }

                response($.map(data, function(item, index) { console.log('l 139', data);
                return item.id+" "+item.firstname1+" "+item.lastname1+" "+item.telephone1;
                    }

                ));//END Success
            },
        });//END AJAX
    },
```

Comment: problem might be the data dismiss. I think when you close an alert it is destroyed.  maybe just make a regular alert.  and if you want it to be dismissible add a button whose on click event is to change the display of the alert to display: none;  then when you want to show it again display it. maybe using jquery .hide and .show

Comment: Why not use a library like bootbox (http://bootboxjs.com/). Not much reason to build alerts from scratch these days.

Comment: believe he is talking about the bootstrap twitter alert box, not a javascript alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear from [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o90rhvdh/) that "something" is happening to the search_customer element on close of the alert.  Notice how the "test" message disappears after the alert is closed.

**JQuery:**

```
$('#test').click(function() {
  $("#search_customer").addClass("alert alert-warning").append('No Such Person Found', "<a href='#' class=close data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close' title='close'>×</a>");

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="search_customer">
  test
</div>
<input id="test" type="button" value="Click Me!">
```

So, inspect that HTML after closing the alert and you'll find the div is gone:
[image: hey where's my div]

This is because `data-dismiss` removes the element.  Goodbye div!

Try using `data-hide` instead, as described here:

[Twitter Bootstrap alert message close and open again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550477/twitter-bootstrap-alert-message-close-and-open-again/13550556#13550556)

P.S.  you're also missing quotes around `class=close`.

---

**Update:**

Even with the above approach, there is still an issue with binding the click event to the dynamically added element. You might consider having your alert loaded in the DOM, but hidden initially. You then can toggle it. [Here is a fiddle showing this approach](https://jsfiddle.net/g02bsgah/1).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have my alert now responding two or more inputs, however I can not get the alerts to close.  I've tried everything. Have a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/vincej/8sm1vsn8/

Comment: @Vince - you're missing required resources on your fiddle.  And the AJAX call in your fiddle will never be successful with a non-public url.  That being said, I believe your issue is with binding the click event to the dynamically added element.  You might consider having your alert loaded in the DOM, but hidden initially.  You then can toggle it.  Here is a fiddle showing this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/g02bsgah/1/

Comment: I got it all to work ! Many thanks ! I had a lot to do after you sent me the fiddle in adapting it to my own situation, but your code certainly set me on the right path.  If you place as a question I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this
https://jsfiddle.net/q5kb0xzk/

```
 <div class="alert alert-warning " id="myalert" style="display: none;" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close"  aria-label="Close" id="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>

$('#btn').click(function(){
 if(!$('#inputEmail3').val().length ){
 $('#myalert').show();
 }else{
  $('#myalert').hide();
 }

})

$('#close').click(function(event){
 $('#myalert').hide();
})
```