# Why jquery function only works once in onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, live, dropdown

The idea: Every time i change the select option, it checks if my data-x property is == "y", If is, an alert Window shows the data-info asociated to this.
This code works great until i try to print this data-info into a div called "result". After this, it only show me the result once, until i refresh my browser, then everything works again. How can i acomplish this? What im doing wrong?

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).children('option:selected').data('x') == 'y') {
      alert($(this).children('option:selected').data('info'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required name="client_id" id="client_id" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" data-show-subtext="true">
  <option value="">-- NONE --</option>
  <option data-info="jUST tESTING" data-x="y" value="2" data-subtext="Santa Maria #1234">Antonio Perez</option>
  <option value="5" data-subtext="AV. Los Cerrillos 602, Chile - Santiago">Tatiana Gutierrez</option>
  <option data-info="aNOTHER tEST" data-x="y" value="6" data-subtext="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Ventas</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ermmm... I think it is working for me.

Comment: Yes it is working fine...

Comment: Unless you  `Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the value of `data-info` attribut of `selected option` to `div`

```
<div id="result"></div>
<select required name="client_id" id="client_id" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" data-show-subtext="true"  >
    <option value="">-- NONE --</option>
    <option  data-info="jUST tESTING" data-x="y"  value="2" data-subtext="Santa Maria #1234">Antonio Perez </option>
    <option  value="5" data-subtext="AV. Los Cerrillos 602, Chile - Santiago">Tatiana Gutierrez </option>
    <option  data-info="aNOTHER tEST" data-x="y"  value="6" data-subtext="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Ventas </option>
</select>


<script>
 $(function () {
   $('select').change(function () {
     if ($(this).children('option:selected').data('x') == 'y') {
         $("#result").html($(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-info'));
     }
     else
         $("#result").html("");
    });
});
    </script>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2sfL91em/) is jsfiddle

Comment: Your answer is correct. I just have a related question for you. I'm using bootstrap alert with close option looks like this <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <p  id="result" >    </p>
</div> . If i close the alert, the select dropdown  stops to show the results. Any idea why?

Comment: @fecapeluda please accept this as correct answer and you can post new question and send me link of that question as code in comments is not clear.

Comment: Please check this meanwhile i start a new question http://codepen.io/lowpez/pen/Woagev

Comment: @fecapeluda what to check in this ?

Comment: click in the "x" or close icon. and try the code, you'll see the function stops working. Seems realted to data-dismiss="alert" tag.

Comment: my friend solved +1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550477/twitter-bootstrap-alert-message-close-and-open-again

Comment: Yeah i was looking at same question :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change load to ready :

```
$('select').change(function(){
   if ($(this).children('option:selected').data('x') == 'y') { 
    alert($(this).children('option:selected').data('info'));
  }
 });
```

});

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).children('option:selected').data('x') == 'y') {
      alert($(this).children('option:selected').data('info'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select required name="client_id" id="client_id" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" data-show-subtext="true">
  <option value="">-- NONE --</option>
  <option data-info="jUST tESTING" data-x="y" value="2" data-subtext="Santa Maria #1234">Antonio Perez</option>
  <option value="5" data-subtext="AV. Los Cerrillos 602, Chile - Santiago">Tatiana Gutierrez</option>
  <option data-info="aNOTHER tEST" data-x="y" value="6" data-subtext="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Ventas</option>
</select>
```