# Alert is not working second time when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert, slidedown

I am using bootstrap version so I have created a slide down menu same like below example.

[button not working second time](http://jsfiddle.net/mfX57/2149/)

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
<strong>Success! </strong>
Product have added to your wishlist.
```

The problem is that when I click on close button in slide down the bar is closing up.

But when I again click on **add wish list** the slide down is not appearing again.

My problem is not only closing. It should close when i click on 'x' button if not it should close automatically after specific time.

Thanks.

Comment: Simple solution would be to just remove the close button as you're hiding it automatically anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap alert message close and open again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550477/twitter-bootstrap-alert-message-close-and-open-again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing whole code .I used `slideUp()` `dealy()` and `slideDown()` methods of Jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#success-alert").hide();
  $("#btn2").click(function showAlert() {
    $("#success-alert").slideDown(300).delay(2000).slideUp(400);
  });
});

$('#success-alert .close').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-options">
  <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Add to wish list" />
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
  <strong>Success! </strong> Product have added to your wishlist.
</div>
```

Comment: I think you didn't see my code @SukumarGorai. There is a difference more-than ID . I didn't pasted your code. check the code of JavaScript. If my code is wrong then down vote, my code is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Remove this from your close button 'data-dismiss="alert"' and add one more click function like below:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    $("#success-alert").hide();
    $("#myWish").click(function showAlert() {
        $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
            $("#success-alert").slideUp(500);
        });   
    });

    $('#success-alert .close').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

HTML will like:

```
<div class="product-options">
    <a  id="myWish" href="javascript:;"  class="btn btn-mini" >Add to Wishlist </a>
    <a  href="" class="btn btn-mini"> Purchase </a>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">
    <button type="button" class="close">x</button>
    <strong>Success! </strong>
    Product have added to your wishlist.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple trick worked for me. Use this `close.bs.alert` bootsrap's event type to hide the element instead of removing it.

```
$('.alert').on('close.bs.alert', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

or

```
$('.alert').on('close.bs.alert', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
});
```