# Show a hidden div element on clicking navbar item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 column of divs in bootstrap, and I can close any div by using-

```
<a href="#card1" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" id="hide">&times;</a>
```

Now I have a side navbar containing the title of the divs that are shown on the body of the page, I want the functionality that on clicking a navbar item , respective div item will re-appear from hidden state.

I tried the following way-

```
function toggleVisibility(id) {

  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

But unfortunately it is not even getting called- and thats why I cannot figure out how to run custom onclick command on navbar `<a>` anchor tags..

My sidenav looks like-

```
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a class="active" href="#home">Overview</a>
    <span  onclick="toggleVisibility('card1')">Card1</span>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('card2')">Card2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('card3')">Card3</a>
  </div>
```

You can see I have used one span and 2  to figure out which one is working- But actually none working.
When the span is in the body of the page it is working correctly , but in the navbar menu items no custom action works.

Here is the jsfiddle to help- https://jsfiddle.net/upyxn7wj/1/
So How to show hidden divs via nav-menu item click-

**N.B: I AM USING Rails and this is for rendering the views I have tried the jsfiddle given by showdev in the comments- but its not working**

Comment: Toggling the visibility by clicking the menu items seems to be working here (Chrome 75)

Comment: can you please clarify or edit the jsfiddle? I could not get it @LinkinTED

Comment: I didn't change anything, it is already working. Clicking a nav item hides the corresponding body item. Clicking it again makes it appear again.

Comment: Confirmed, it does work

Comment: Try closing the nav and check again. The contents of the cards make me think that it's not working at first glance

Comment: I just saw that clicking the close button do not make the divs disappear, that is why maybe you are seeing this as clicking any nav menu item it refreshes the page , nothing else, I want only the particular item back

Comment: If you observe the respective divs elements closely, you can findout its not working

Comment: I think Bootstrap's `data-dismiss` will remove the element from the DOM, so making it reappear might be more difficult than it seems.

Comment: so what should be a better way to achieve the intended functionality without data-dismiss?

Comment: [One answer at the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43010949/924299) details a possible solution by intercepting the `close.bs.alert` [event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#events). "The reason why Bootstrap exposes this event type is so that you can overwrite the default behavior of removing the alert from the DOM." Then you can use elements in your sidenav to, for example, `.removeClass('hidden');`.

Comment: My case is not for alert , its for div I have still checked with your reference , its bringing back all the three divs together regardless of what div is hidden @showdev

Comment: [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/kz81ejq0/) based on the referenced `close.bs.alert` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code,

```
function toggleVisibility(id) {
    /* START : Code to disable the other div's on click */
            var xVal = document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-4");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < xVal.length; i++) {
                xVal[i].style.display = "none";
               }
   /* END: Code to disable the other div's on click */
          var x = document.getElementById(id);
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "inline";
          } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
```

instead of "col-md-4" you put one more class name for those div's and use it in the code.

Comment: its not working its removing other visible and present divs !!